# $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ satisfies the descending chain condition of divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ satisfies the descending chain condition of divisors: given a chain $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n,\dots$ and $a_{n+1}\mid a_n$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then there is a positive integer $m$ such that $a_m\sim a_{m+1}\sim\cdots$.

I tried to use the multiplicative norm $N$ defined on $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-5}]$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID, there must exist a positive integer $m$ such that $N(a_m)=N(a_{m+1})=\cdots$. But I am stuck in here because $N(a+b\sqrt{-5})=N(\alpha+\beta\sqrt{-5})$ does not imply $a+b\sqrt{-5}\sim \alpha+\beta\sqrt{-5}$ in general. Am I on the right track? Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that in case the norms in the chain are equal the codivior has norm $1$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]\cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+5)$ is Noetherian, so the chain of ideals $(a_1)\subset (a_2) \subset \dots$ is eventuallly constant.

Comment: @ArtW: $N(12+6\sqrt{-5})=N(2+8\sqrt{-5})=324$. $12+6\sqrt{-5}$ is not equivalent to $2+8\sqrt{-5}$ since $\pm 1$ are only units in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Comment: Oh dang I'm sorry. Nice example

Comment: @ArW: Thank you for the answer. It is assumed that I do not know Noetherian rings and Hilbert basis theorem. It seems like there exists an elementary proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you begin, let $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ nonnegative such that $$N(a_m)=N(a_{m+1})=\dots$$
(assume they're not all zero).

Let $k\ge m$ and let $b_k\in\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ such that $a_k=a_{k+1}\cdot b_k$ (exists by $a_{k+1}\mid a_k$). Then by $N(a_k)=N(a_{k+1})$ and multiplicativity of the norm we have $N(b_k)=1$ so $a_k\sim a_{k+1}$.